# Calling a MS SQL Server scalar UDF from vba

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I am programming an Access 2007 (accdb, not adp) frontend at connect to a SQL Server 2005 backend. How can I call a **scalar** user defined function from my vba code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Set rst = Connection.Execute("SELECT dbo.MyFunction('" & Me.field & "')")
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a query that calls the function.

```
SELECT [FirstName], [Surname]
  FROM dbo.FindCustomersOrderByDesc();
```

Comment: @Ardman, the function you calling here is a _table_ valued function. Do you know a simple way to call a _scalar_ function?

Comment: Yes, just do a SELECT function.  This will give you the results you want.  I added the table valued function in order to show you it's the same method.