# Calling scalar UDF function from ms access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, user-defined-functions

I am trying to call a scalar function from my database in ms access.
This function should return one row of my salted and hashed parameters.

My initial attemt looked like this and returned the following error: "undefined function 'dbo.SaltAndHashPassword' in expression"

```
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT dbo.SaltAndHashPassword('" & Me.txtWW & "','" & Me.salt & "') as salted", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
```

I tried the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477684/calling-a-ms-sql-server-scalar-udf-from-vba?rq=1) but I got the error "object required"

I also tried the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388885/calling-a-udf-sql-server-from-vb-access-undefined-function-function-name-in) but I can't get it to work(probably due to wrong parameters)

Can anybody help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `CurrentDb`in that case. You have to set a `Connection` object to the server/db where the  `dbo.SaltAndHashPassword` function is stored (the example you mention uses a connection, even if the code to set it up is not shown), since it is  totally unknown from Access.
Alternatively you can create a passthru query in Access and use DAO. I find it easier and it avoids creating yet another external reference.

---

Something like:

```
   Set db = CurrentDb()
   'Create a temporary passthrough query ' 
   Set ptq = db.CreateQueryDef("")
   'set ODBC connection  '
   ptq.Connect = "your connect string"
   ptq.SQL = "SELECT * from your SQL"
   ptq.ReturnsRecords = True
   Set rs = ptq.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)
```

Comment: Thanks, How would I either set a connection object or create a passthru query using a DAO then?